# Set binding from ItemsSource to Label in ListView DataTemplate without XAML

Tags: c#, xamarin, binding

I've created `DataTemplate` for my `ListView` but text of `ListViewItems` is not displaying. How to bind text from `ItemsSource`?

```
List<string> stringList;

ListView myListView = new ListView 
{
    ItemsSource = stringList,
    ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => 
    {
        StackLayout sl = new StackLayout 
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
        };
        sl.Children.Add(new Label 
        {
            FontSize = 14,   
        });

        return new ViewCell { View = sl };
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize your label before adding to your StackLayout, call it `temp` for example and `bind` it like this to a custom object:

```
temp.SetBinding (Label.TextProperty, "TemplatePropertyThatYouWish");
```

And this to a list of strings:

```
temp.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, ".");
```

Then add it to your StackLayout.

Code:

```
List<string> stringList = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };

ListView myListView = new ListView
{
    ItemsSource = stringList,
    ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
    {
        StackLayout sl = new StackLayout
        {
             VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
             Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
        };

        var temp = new Label
        {
            FontSize = 14,
        };

        temp.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, ".");

        sl.Children.Add(temp);

        return new ViewCell { View = sl };
   })
};
```

Comment: But what second argument I have to use if I need to bind my ItemSource with string list?

Comment: Updated @InfernumDeus